# How to get value for Client_id and Client_Secret to call API from Postman

Tags: ringcentral

I am trying to call RingCentral API from Postman. This is my first attempt and so I am following what is provided by RingCentral documentation: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/messaging/sms/postman

I created a Sandbox account and an API app which uses following authorization:

[image]

However, when I call from the Postman, I am getting following error:

```json
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorCode": "OAU-251",
            "message": "Unauthorized for this grant type"
        }
    ],
    "error_description": "Unauthorized for this grant type"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you followed the "pre requisites" section in that page?  The client id and secret will come from the app you register

Comment: Yes, I created app so that I can get details, at present, I got the client id and credential, but when I call the Auth API, I am getting "errorCode": "OAU-251",
            "message": "Unauthorized for this grant type"

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a [JWT Auth flow](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication/jwt/create-jwt)

Comment: I am not able to use JWT, getting message below: "Your sandbox account must be in active status to select this option." However, when I check the Sandbox, it is active.